# Yiddish song about children learning the aleph-bet in a warm room

Tags: song-poetry, yiddish

I am looking for information about an old Yidish song with a very well-known tune.

The only information I have about this song is that it talks about Kinderlach sitting in a warm room and learning the Aleph-Beth and the Torah with their Melammed.

This is not much information, but, maybe some of you can identify the song and give me some information about its words?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78384

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're most likely looking for [Oifen Pripitchik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oyfn_Pripetshik).

See it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkS3cZntDTY

The lyrics are brought in the WikiPedia article in both Yiddish and English Translation.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi a pleasure. Actually I myself was looking for this song's name after watching Schindlers List. The movie plays it during a massacre as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 4):

You must be talking about the song אויפן פריפעטשיק (Oyfn Pripetshik). The lyrics are listed below (according to the version sung by Ester Ofarim):

.אויפן פריפעטשיק ברענט א פייערל, און אין שטוב איז הייס
.און דער רבי לערנט קליינע קינדערלעך דעם אלף-בית

.זעט זשע קינדערלעך געדענקט זשע טייערע, וואס איר לערנט דא
!זאגט זשע נאך א מאל און טאקע נאך א מאל: קמץ-אלף - א

.לערנט קינדערלעך, לערנט מיט פרייד, לערנט דעם אלף-בית
.גליקלעך איז דער איד וואס קענט די תורה, און דאס אלף-בית

And now, for transliteration and the *taytsh:*

Oyfn pripetshik brent a fayerl, un in shtub iz heys. Un der rebe lernt kleyne kinderlekh, dem alef-beyz.

Zet zhe kinderlekh, gedenkt zhe tayere, vos ir lernt do.
Zogt zhe nokh a mol un take nokh a mol: komets-alef - o!

Lernt kinderlekh, lernt mit freyd, lernt dem alef-beyz.
Gliklekh iz der yid vos kent di toyre, un dos alef-beyz.

On the hearth, a little fire burns and in the room it's warm. And the rabbi teaches little children the alphabet (Alef-Beis).

[Rabbi speaking] "See you children, dear, remember dear, what you're learning here. Say it once again and repeat it once again: Komets-Alef - o! (The Yiddish letter komets-alef makes the sound of o as in dog.)

Learn, children, learn with happiness, learn the alphabet. Happy is the Jew who knows the Torah and the alphabet.

Hopes this helps. Also, here's a link to the song:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUF-jHyEuNg

(BTW, one of my favorite songs!)