# Does a non-Jew learn in the womb the same way a Jew does?

Tags: gentiles, torah-study, pregnancy-birth

At every stage of a person’s existence, Torah is part of it.

1. “When you are sitting at home” (meaning in the womb)
2. “when you are going on the road,” (meaning the soul descends from the world above to the world below)
3. "when you lie down.” (Meaning when he lies down in his grave)
4. “And when you rise up” (referring to the era of the resurrection of the dead)

(From [Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/407107/jewish/Four-Stages-in-Torah-Learning.htm), from Deuteronomy 6:7.)

Does a non-Jewish soul go through the same process as explained here as far as Torah learning (in the womb)?

Comment: Stage 2 (during one's lifetime) only applies to Jews (as non-Jews have no obligation/possibly forbidden to learn Torah). Why should the rest of the phrase apply to non-Jews?

Comment: Care to explain what "in the womb" means?

Comment: Perhaps the link above will explain better then I can.

Answer (score 4):

Someone told me that he asked this question to רבי יצחק רצאבי [Rabbi Yitzchok Ratzabi](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99) and he said that non Jews learn the seven Mitzvos that are applicable to them while in the womb.

For R. Ratzabi's disucussion of the matter, see [here](http://www.maharitz.co.il/?CategoryID=252&ArticleID=2135).

Answer (score 4):

The [Chid"a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai) ([Pesach Einayim. NId. 30b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40655&st=&pgnum=313)) mentions the opinion that gentiles are taught the seven Noahide laws in the womb but he disagrees and maintains that gentiles are not taught even the seven Noahide laws since it is forbidden to teach them any Torah at all ([BT Hag. 13a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%92%D7%99%D7%92%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%90)), and the Noahide laws that they *are* bidden to keep is not considered abiding by Torah rather they are ethical laws which they need to observe. [Rabbi Rachamim Palacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahamim_Nissim_Palacci) ([Yafeh LaLev YD 246:21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7660&st=&pgnum=95)) at first assumes that the reason why it is forbidden to teach Torah to gentiles is because they would then be "reminded" of the Torah they were taught in the womb and the teacher is thereby in transgression of "returning a lost item to its [gentile] owner". He then seems to toy with the idea that they are taught some Torah in case they convert to Judaism during their lifetime.

Comment: This Chida is surprising for the Gemara in Sanhedrin says that the prohibition of a non-Jew studying Torah does not apply to the Noahide laws.